# get запрос через VBA Excel перестал работать

Tags: excel

Кратко о проблеме Excel, VBA (до 11 сентября 2019 все работало)

sQuery = "[https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=РФ,+г.+Санкт-Петербург,+б-р+Серебристый,+д.+26,+литера+А,+кв.+187](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=%D0%A0%D0%A4,+%D0%B3.+%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3,+%D0%B1-%D1%80+%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9,+%D0%B4.+26,+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%90,+%D0%BA%D0%B2.+187)"

xhrRequest.Open "GET", sQuery, False

ответ сервера -  ÐÔ, ã. Ñàíêò-Ïåòåðáóðã, á-ð Ñåðåáðèñòûé, ä. 26, ëèòåðà À, êâ. 187
- не найдено-

Если адрес писать на английском, все работает. 
Использовал этот вызов очень давно, на своей стороне ничего не делал. 
Стало ломать кодировку. Как с этим бороться в VBA не знаю. 
Этот же запрос через броузер - все норм.
Как лечить?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Нужно было перекодировать русский текст. Почему работало раньше, не знаю. Что то обновили на API.карты и теперь перекодировать.

Comment: Напишите плз как решили задачу (как перекодировали)? Пробовал перекодировать по всякому, не получается пока...

Comment: @Алексей перекодировка доступна при сохранении документа сохранить как/сервис-> параметры веб документа/utf8

Comment: @Ruslan Semenov, проблема не в сохранении документа, а в том что отправляемый запрос в яндекс судя по всему уже кодирован не в той кодировки, в которой хочет принять его api.яндекс карт. Поэтому возвращается "урезанный ответ" с кракозябюрами вместо адреса. Если послать тот же запрос через браузер или транслитом, то приходит полный ответ с геокодом и прочей информацией. ps уважаемая администрация, я в курсе что это сообщение нужно писать в "комментарии", но для этого система требует 50 баллов репутации, при этом для добавления "ответа" репутация не требуется ¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯